# Example integrable function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I'm looking for an example of an integrable function that is discontinuous in an infinite set. So I am actually looking for an example that satisfies that, but I don't know how to get started. I'd appreciate any hits of functions so that I could try to prove that it is discontinuous in an infinite set.

Comment: Let $f$ be the characteristic function of the set $\{ {1 \over n} \}$, $n=1,2...$.

Comment: Search.  Find (easily) an example of a Riemann integrable function on $[0,1]$ that is discontinuous at each rational point.  Then look (a little deeper) for one that is discontinuous on an uncountable set.  As the other comment shows, finding just a countable set of points of discontinuity is rather easy and also uninteresting.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) := \frac{1}{\lceil x^2 \rceil}$ then $\int_0^{\infty}f(x) dx < \infty$ but it is discontinuous over a (countably) infinite set.

Comment: This function is discontinuous over a finite set, that is {0}. So that does not follow what I am actually looking for.

Comment: No — it has jumps whenever $x^2$ is an integer

Comment: @Mathematician — I wonder if you missed the ceiling symbols — this leads to countably infinite discontinuities